# Setting max heap size in JVM args for bootRun in Grails 3 build.gradle file breaks debug capability in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, grails

I am currently running a Grails 3.2.13 application and attempting to increase the max heapsize. I am running the application using a Grails run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.

I set the jvmArgs in the bootRun configuration of the build.gradle file like so:

```
bootRun {
  jvmArgs=['-Xmx2048m']
}
```

That seems to do the trick as far as setting the correct heapsize, but it also seems to override whatever settings IntelliJ would normally put there, including the setting of the port for the debugger to connect to, which seems to be different every time.

I would like to append this new setting onto the JVM args, but everything I try seems to overwrite the debug settings.

I've also tried editing the run configuration in IntelliJ and setting the heapsize in the VM options there, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Isn't there a `-` missing before the argument?

Comment: Are you using the gradle runner inside intellij (might not yet be a thing in '17)

Comment: @cfrick, sorry yes, unfortunately that was a typo in the question but not my build file, also I am using a run/debug configuration inside IntelliJ for Grails. `Run>Edit Configurations > Grails`

Comment: For anyone who is looking, I have found a workaround that doesn't help in the case of overriding the jvmArgs, but it has helped me achieve both increasing the heapsize and being able to debug.

I set the jvmArgs in the bootRun config to `['-Xmx2048m', '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=62092,suspend=n,server=y']` which allows me to run the app, and then connect the debugger to port 62092 with `Run > Attach to Local Process... > [Your Application Here]`

Comment: If you run the grails/gradle/application directly you have to configure all that jazz in via "edit config". you can click on the first line in your "terminal" inside intellij to see what it actually runs.